# Работа со сложным объектом

Tags: javascript

Есть объект client который включает в себя индексированные массивы `client.yl` `client.fl` и `client.au`, выглядит примерно так:

```
client = {};

client.yl = [
{
    name:"ООО «Рога и копыта»",
    inn:"23457567546",
    ogrn:"1234567890987",
    address:"г. Москва, Красная площадь д.1"
},  

{
    name:"ООО «СМУ-4»",
    inn:"2222222",
    ogrn:"535353535",
    address:"г. Нижний Новгород, ул. Ленина 17",
    nameLong:"ООО «Строительно-монтажное управление № 4» (ООО «СМУ-4»)"
},  

{
    name:"Ромашка",
    inn:"33333333",
    ogrn:"2222222222222",
    address:"г. Москва, ул. Тверская-Ямская 18"
},  
]

client.fl = [
{...},
{...},
{...}
]

client.au = [
{...},
{...},
{...}
]
```

Я хочу сделать двухмерный перебор свойств, т.е. сначала for...in перебор свойств yl/fl/au корневого объекта client, а потом перебор значений массива с числовыми индексами. Однако при попытке провести перебор свойств корневого объекта

```
for (i in client)  {
console.log(i);
}
```

возвращаются названия вложенных объектов как строки

```
yl 
fl
au
```

а при попытке вывести client.i

```
for (i in client)  {
   console.log(client.i);
}
```

выдает

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Как в данном случае работать со вложенными массивами? Почему возвращается имя переменной, а не сам массив?

Comment: А так `client[i]`? Дело в том, что `i` в данном случае просто строка, а обратиться к свойству объекта через строку можно только через квадратные скобки.

Comment: Так работает, сглупил, спасибо.